# Unknown site using jquery and css file but include my site path

Tags: php, wordpress, css, jquery

This is my site URL - https://www.thecodedeveloper.com

But this Unknown site http://newnuk.com/dialio/Web_doctor/viewinfo/139

means i am not owner of this site

But once i view source this page http://newnuk.com/dialio/Web_doctor/viewinfo/139 
then i found on this page include below files

https://www.thecodedeveloper.com/wp-content/themes/publisher-child/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />

these files path coming from my site.

I want to know:
1) Is that effect my site speed ?
2) how can i stop it ?

Thanks

Comment: I feel this question is better suited for [webmasters.se]. There is even a [tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/hotlinking) specifically for this subject. It's quite likely that this is a duplicate of a question which was already asked there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that ListingHub is "hotlinking" your script. You can prevent this by modifying the .htaccess file. The following will allow only your domain to access resources.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)thecodedeveloper.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|js|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

They are using your bandwidth by calling the script from your server so yes, it could negatively affect the performance of your site.

Comment: it's call hot linking. i got it. Before i tried to search on google, but didn't get right answer because i was not searching with right word but now i can fix this issue.

Comment: is that effect Google search engine ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "is that effect Google search engine" in relation to your question.